# 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' error in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

What I am attempting to do is to make it so that when I enter into a text input and then press "submit" the text will be printed. However this is not working and I instead recieve the error "'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'". I have attempted to place they python code in different classes however this also does not work. Attached bellow is the relevant code as well as the full code along with the error message tht I recieved.
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOgOJ.png)

Any help with this issue would be appreciated as I am new to kivy so I don't fully understand all of it's quirks.

The offending part of code in python is:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = [300, 600]
        return Builder.load_file("screen.kv")
    def returnusername(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print(text)
    def returnpassword(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print(text)
```

The offending part of code in kivy is:

```
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Submit"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
            on_release: 
                app.returnusername()
                app.returnpassword()
```

Full Python Code:

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class FirstPageScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class LoginPageScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class NewAccountScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = [300, 600]
        return Builder.load_file("screen.kv")
    def returnusername(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print(text)
    def returnpassword(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print(text)

  
MainApp().run()
```

Full Kivy Code:

```
#:kivy  2.0.0

WindowManager:
    FirstPageScreen:
    LoginPageScreen:
    NewAccountScreen:

<FirstPageScreen>:
    name: "FirstPage"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Time Saving App"
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            font_size: 25
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.85}

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Login"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "LoginPage" 
                

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Create new account"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.65}
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "NewAccount" 

<LoginPageScreen>:
    name: "LoginPage"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Login"
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            font_size: 25
            pos: (0,220)
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Back"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "FirstPage"
        TextInput:
            id: usernameinput
            hint_text:'Enter your Username'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: passwordinput
            hint_text:'Enter your Password'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            multiline: False
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Submit"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
            on_release: 
                app.returnusername()
                app.returnpassword()
        

<NewAccountScreen>:
    name: "NewAccount"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Create New account"
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            font_size: 25
            pos: (0,220)
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Back"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "FirstPage"
        TextInput:
            id: newusernameinput
            hint_text:'Enter a Username'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id: newpasswordinput
            hint_text:'Enter a Password'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.05
            multiline: False
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"
            text: "Submit"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
            on_release: 
                pass
```

Comment: Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `self.root.ids.input.text` is trying to reference `ids` in the app `root`. There are two problems with that. First, the root is the `WindowManager`, which has no `ids` in your code. Second, there is no `input` `id` defined in your `kv`. The fix is to define an `input` `id` somewhere in your `kv`, and then use something like

```
self.root.get_screen('some_screen_name').ids.input.text
```

where `some_screen_name` is the `name` of the `Screen` that contains the `input` `id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John Anderson, it has been very helpful and the issue has now been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

your screen manager should look like this

```
WindowManager:
    FirstPageScreen:
        id: first_page_screen
        name: first_page_screen
    LoginPageScreen:
        id: login_page_screen
        name: login_page_screen
    NewAccountScreen:
        id: new_account_screen
        name: new_account_screen
```

your screens in the screen manager need to have ids and names so as to make them easier to reference from the screen manager

move the `returnusername` and `returnpassword` functions to the calling class, which will make them easier to access.

the button on the `LoginPageScreen` which made the call would look like this

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    halign: "center"
    valign: "center"
    text: "Submit"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    md_bg_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    line_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
    on_release: 
        root.returnusername()
        root.returnpassword()
```

and the functions in the `LoginScreenPage` class would be as below

```
class LoginPageScreen(MDScreen):
    def returnusername(self):
        text = self.ids.usernameinput.text
        print(text)
    def returnpassword(self):
        text = self.ids.passwordinput.text
        print(text)
```

in your `kv` file, `<FirstPageScreen>:`, `<LoginPageScreen>:`, `<NewAccountScreen>:` should no longer have the name attribute. that has been added in the screen manager. so calling the the screens with `app.root.current` will point to the new screen names added to screen manager.

Sometime how you structure your code affect how you understand the code and how to debug errors.